# Offset displayed data 4 hours forward on HighCharts x axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, momentjs, series

I have existing charts that displays data for a full day 12:00am - 12:00am.

[image: chart 12am - 12am]

Now required to change one chart forward to display 4:00am - 4:00am.

I have managed to shift the x axis labels (.add(4, 'hours')) but the chart data is still in the same position.

[image: 4am - 4am x axis labels]

How do I shift the charted data forward 4 hours?

Limited scope to change global variables as this will impact other charts.

```
var getChartSeries = function(response, chart_series_data) {
        var lines = response.graph_data.lines;
        for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
            var series = lines[i];
            var dateFormat = graphDateFormat;
            if (chartIntraday) dateFormat = 'HH:mm:ss';
            var currSeriesData = [];
            for (var j=0; j<series.data.length; j++) {
                var row = series.data[j];
                var yValue = parseFloat(row[1]);
                var point = {
                    x: moment(row[0], dateFormat).add(4, 'hours').valueOf(),
                    y: yValue,
                    displayValue: row[3]
                };
                currSeriesData.push(point);
            }
            // Set the series name, legend label, and the line identifier
            var name = formatLegendLabel(series.display_name, response);
            var label = response.label;
            if (response.display_name != undefined && response.display_name != '') label = series.display_name + ' : ' + label;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default chart adjusts extremes to the provided data. To display these few hours before the first point use `xAxis.min` property.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/xqdqooh9/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

Comment: I got some help and the Django/SQL query was adjusted to a different range.Thanks for your input.